# My Moto X (2014) cannot run the debugging mode

Tags: android, macos, debugging

I am using Mac OS with my Moto X (2014) for developing apps.

My Moto X just cannot activate the debugging mode when I connect to my Mac.

I've tried to use another Android phone, and it works so far, and I am sure that it's not the problem of USB cable.

And I also tried to connect my Moto X to the other Mac, and the debugging mode doesn't activate either.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: After I reset my phone, it's still not work now...